# MicroChip Sample Code setting Current to a CMPDAC, DAC threshold which expect an voltage

Tags: embedded, microcontroller, pic, microchip

Sorry,  the Microchip Forum is very slow, I prefer to use Stack Overflow to ask questions.

```
dsPIC33FJ06GS101/X02 and dsPIC33FJ16GSX02/X04    device 

 Sample Code   
              // configure comparator2  


    CMPCON2bits.CMPON = 1;   // enable comparator 
CMPCON2bits.INSEL = 1;   // select CMP2B input pin (RB0) 
CMPCON2bits.RANGE = 1;   // select high range, max DAC value = Avdd/2        
//CMPDACx: COMPARATOR DAC CONTROL REGISTER        
//CMREF<9:0>: Comparator Reference Voltage Select bits 
CMPDAC2 = CURR_HWLIM;    // DAC threshold 


  #define CURR_HWLIM 1023 // 1023 // 10.15 * 101A
```

Microchip sample code setting `CURR_HWLIM` which is 1023A to `CMPDAC2`, which expects voltage.

Is that a mistake?

Answer (score 0):

See **REGISTER 20-2: CMPDACx: COMPARATOR DAC CONTROL REGISTER** in the datasheet:

```
bit 9-0 CMREF<9:0>: Comparator Reference Voltage Select bits

1111111111 = (CMREF * INTREF/1024) or (CMREF * (AVDD/2)/1024) volts depending on
RANGE bit or (CMREF * EXTREF/1024) if EXTREF is set
.
.
.
0000000000 = 0.0 volts
```

`RANGE` bit seems to be set to `1`, so the formula is `VOLTAGE = CMPDAC2 * (AVDD/2) / 1024`.

To calculate the digital value from input voltage, use `CMPDAC2 = 1024 * VOLTAGE / (AVDD/2)`.